# Python Extracting First Link in Google Search

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, urllib

I am trying to send in a search query into Google, and extract just the first result found.  I need just the URL.  Here is a sample of what I've tried so far, but for some reason I cannot grab the href value.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import xlwt
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from urllib.parse import urlparse

name = "Joe Sample"
search_query = 'string of info ' + name + ' more info'


driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path="geckodriver")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
driver.find_element_by_name('q').send_keys(search_query)
time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="tsf"]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/center/input[1]').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)



results = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div[2]/div[10]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/span/div/ol/li/a')
    href = results.get_attribute('href')
    print(urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse(href).query)['q'])
```

First half of the code is working correctly, issue is finding the first link--and grabbing only the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I’m assuming it should be `href = results[0].get_attribute(“href”)`